# Elegant way to get all categorical columns in pandas?

Tags: numpy, pandas, scipy

Is there a way to get all categorical variables in Pandas? The best way I know is to iterate through all columns and check whether the `dtype` is categorical.

Ultimately, I'd like a one-liner to plot all bar charts of all categorical variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and pass the `'category'` as the type to filter the df by, this will return all columns where the `dtype` matches this:

```
In [9]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(6),
                    'b': [True, False] * 3,
                    'c': [1.0, 2.0] * 3})
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    6 non-null float64
b    6 non-null bool
c    6 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(1), float64(2)
memory usage: 150.0 bytes

In [10]:
df['a'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'])
df['c'] = pd.Categorical(df['c'])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    6 non-null category
b    6 non-null bool
c    6 non-null category
dtypes: bool(1), category(2)
memory usage: 130.0 bytes

In [11]:
df.select_dtypes(['category'])

Out[11]:
          a  c
0  1.295878  1
1 -1.230722  2
2  0.340209  1
3 -0.277246  2
4 -2.336386  1
5  0.363829  2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
catCols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype=="O"]
```

catcols is a list will have all the columns from df whose type is O which is object